# Can't mount Windows drive to view files

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have two hard drives. On the one hard drive Windows 7 & 8 is installed, on the other Ubuntu. When I try to mount the drive, I get this message.

[image]

Comment: Which image? Please upload it on http://imgur.com/ and post the link here. You cannot upload images directly as you are a low rep user.

Comment: the link is http://i.imgur.com/lfRS2Lt.png

Comment: I have added an answer, Your image shows that windows is in unsafe state i.e. hibernated or not properly shutdown

Comment: ...And a bunch of others

Answer (score 1):

You have probably hibernated your Windows.

Boot into windows, disable fast shutdown in Windows, fully shut windows down properly (do not hibernate), and then boot into ubuntu and you will be able to mount drives properly.